# First script: Errors on choice selection and IF statements

Tags: batch-file

This is my code if you want to run it yourself just copy it and save as .bat.
Its meant to be a scissors Paper Rock to see if i could make a game in batch, it keeps closing after you make a choice between scissors paper rock.

```
@echo off  
:setting  
title Scissors, Paper, Rock  

`Choosing between Scissors, Paper and Rock`
:an  
set /a ran=%random%  
if /i %ran% GTR 3 goto an  
if /i %ran% LSS 1 goto an  
if %ran%==1 set %ans%=Scissors  
if %ran%==2 set %ans%=Paper  
if %ran%==3 set %ans%=Rock  

`Human Making a Choice`
:in  
echo Choose:  
echo [1] = Scissors  
echo [2] = Paper  
echo [3] = Rock  
set /p text=  
if text==1 goto 1  
else if text==2 goto 2  
else if text==3 goto 3  

`Outcome`
:1  
echo You chose Scissors. The Computer chooses %ans%  
if %ans%==Scissors echo Draw  
if %ans%==Paper echo Win  
if %ans%==Rock echo Loose  
pause  
goto out  

`Outcome`
:2  
echo You chose Paper. The Computer chooses %ans%  
if %ans%==Scissors echo Loose  
if %ans%==Paper echo Draw  
if %ans%==Rock echo Win  
pause  
goto out  

`Outcome`
:3  
echo You chose Rock. The Computer chooses %ans%  
if %ans%==Scissors echo Win  
if %ans%==Paper echo Loose  
if %ans%==Rock echo Draw  
pause  
goto out  

`Play again or not`
:out  
echo GG Want to play again?  
echo [1] = Yes  
echo [2] = No  
set /p text=  
if text==1 goto setting  
if text==2 pause
```

Thanks if you guys can help its really appreciated because i'm really confused right now.

Comment: Sorry lose*......

Comment: Open the command prompt and run the script from there instead of double-clicking it. You'll see exactly what's wrong (hint: it's lines 22 and 23). (And honestly, the backticks probably aren't helping things either.)

Comment: Additional hint, You have these at the end of every line, twice!

Comment: yeah sorry the back ticks i couldnt post the question without explaining the code i couldnt work out how to do it back ticks was what i thought.... sorry

Comment: I suggest to carefully read the answer on [How to stop Windows command interpreter from quitting batch file execution on an incorrect user input?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49834019/3074564)

Answer (score 1):

- Using choice.exe you can save some of the input validation as it prevents illegal inputs.
- `set /a` allows several calculations in one command and doesn't require enclosing vars in `%/!`
- the batch loops (with a timeout delay) and maintains a score.
- fetches the users first name from `net user`

---

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\07\22\SO_51462128.cmd
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
title Scissors, Paper, Rock

:: build array of ans[] 
Set "ans[1]=Scissors"&Set "ans[2]=Paper"&Set "ans[3]=Rock"
Set /A "wins=Draw=Loss=0"

:: Get User first name
For /f "tokens=1-3,*" %%A in (
  'net user "%USERNAME%" ^| findstr /i /B "..ll"'
) Do set "FirstName=%%C"

:restart
cls
Echo Hi %FirstName%, let's play.                %Score%

REM Choosing between Scissors, Paper and Rock
SET /A "min=1,max=3,Comp=(%RANDOM% %% max)+min"
Set "ans=!ans[%Comp%]!"

REM Human Making a Choice
echo Choose:
echo [1] = Scissors
echo [2] = Paper
echo [3] = Rock
Choice /CS /C 123e /M "e to exit"
set "User=%ErrorLevel%"
If %User%==4 exit /B
echo You chose !ans[%User%]!. The Computer chooses !ans[%Comp%]!
If %User%==%Comp% Call :Score Draw & Goto :ReStart
goto :Outcome%User%

:Outcome1 Scissors
if %ans%==Paper Call :Score Wins & Goto :ReStart
Call :Score Loss & Goto :ReStart

:Outcome2 Paper
if %ans%==Rock Call :Score Wins & Goto :ReStart
Call :Score Loss & Goto :ReStart

:Outcome3 Rock
if %ans%==Scissors Call :Score Wins & Goto :ReStart
Call :Score Loss & Goto :ReStart

:Score
Echo **%1**
set /A "%1+=1"
Set "Score=Wins:[%Wins%] Draw:[%Draw%] Loss:[%Loss%]"
timeout /t 5 >Nul
```

Sample output:

```
Hi LotPings, let's play.                Wins:[4] Draw:[4] Loss:[1]
Choose:
[1] = Scissors
[2] = Paper
[3] = Rock
e to exit [1,2,3,e]?
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several techniques that are common in computer programs in order to write simpler and shorter code. One of the most used is the *array*, because it allows to use *the same code* with different values and just use the right value to select the appropriate array element. You may read about array management in Batch files at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990).

The code below does *not* manage each item (Scissors, Paper or Rock) in individual way, but manages all of them in the same way and the appropriate item is selected via a numeric *index* or *subscript*. The program uses a simple trick in order to accomodate the cyclic nature of the three items. An arithmetic expression converts a `0` (meaning "Paper less than Scissors") to `3` (meaning "Paper greater than Rock") only when the opponent's item is a Rock.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
title Scissors, Paper, Rock

rem Define array of items in "natural" (cyclic) order
set "item[0]=Paper"
set "item[1]=Scissors"
set "item[2]=Rock"
set "item[3]=Paper"
set /A "Loss=0, Draw=0, Wins=0"

cls
:loop
echo/

rem Choosing between Scissors, Paper and Rock
set /A "comp=%random% %% 3"

rem Human Making a Choice
choice /N /C PSRe /M "Choose Scissors, Paper or Rock (E to exit): "
if %errorlevel% equ 4 exit /B

set /A "human=%errorlevel%-1, comp+=^!comp*^!(human-2)*3, human+=^!human*^!(comp-2)*3"
echo You chose !item[%human%]!. The Computer chooses !item[%comp%]!.

if %human% gtr %comp% (
   set /A Wins+=1
) else if %human% lss %comp% (
   set /A Loss+=1
) else (
   set /A Draw+=1
)

echo Loss: %Loss%  -  Draw: %Draw%  -  Wins: %Wins%
goto loop
```

In the code below the three different score results (Loss, Draw and Wins) are not managed as individual items anymore, but calculated in the same way as elements of the same `score` array. A very simple expression replaces the several `if` commands used for the score identification into a single value between `0` and `2`.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
title Scissors, Paper, Rock

rem Define array of items in "natural" (cyclic) order
set "item[0]=Paper"
set "item[1]=Scissors"
set "item[2]=Rock"
set "item[3]=Paper"

rem Define the elements of the "score" results array
set /A "score[0]=0, score[1]=0, score[2]=0"

cls
:loop
echo

rem Choosing between Scissors, Paper and Rock
set /A "comp=%random% %% 3"

rem Human Making a Choice
choice /N /C PSRe /M "Choose Scissors, Paper or Rock (E to exit): "
if %errorlevel% equ 4 exit /B

set /A "human=%errorlevel%-1, comp+=^!comp*^!(human-2)*3, human+=^!human*^!(comp-2)*3, result=human-comp+1"
echo You chose !item[%human%]!. The Computer chooses !item[%comp%]!.

set /A "score[%result%]+=1"
echo Loss: %score[0]%  -  Draw: %score[1]%  -  Wins: %score[2]%
goto loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Re did some code and added remarks.

```
@echo off
:setting
title Scissors, Paper, Rock

REM Choosing between Scissors, Paper and Rock
:an
:: Changed the way you generate the random number as it makes it much quick. This forced the answer to be 1, 2 or 3.
SET maxvalue=3
SET minvalue=1
SET /A ran=((%RANDOM%)%%(%maxvalue%))+(%minvalue%)
:: As you are comparing numbers, use the EQU, not ==. == is for comparing strings, not numerical values
:: When setting a variable, don't use the % sign, just type their name and call it with the % sign.
if %ran% equ 1 set ans=Scissors
if %ran% equ 2 set ans=Paper
if %ran% equ 3 set ans=Rock
if /i %ran% GTR 3 goto :an
if /i %ran% LSS 1 goto :an

REM Human Making a Choice
:in
echo Choose:
echo [1] = Scissors
echo [2] = Paper
echo [3] = Rock
set /p text=
if %text% equ 1 goto :1
if %text% equ 2 goto :2
if %text% equ 3 goto :3

REM Outcome
:1
echo You chose Scissors. The Computer chooses %ans%
if %ans%==Scissors echo Draw
if %ans%==Paper echo Win
if %ans%==Rock echo Loose
pause
goto :out

REM Outcome
:2
echo You chose Paper. The Computer chooses %ans%
if %ans%==Scissors echo Loose
if %ans%==Paper echo Draw
if %ans%==Rock echo Win
pause
goto :out

REM Outcome
:3
echo You chose Rock. The Computer chooses %ans%
if %ans%==Scissors echo Win
if %ans%==Paper echo Loose
if %ans%==Rock echo Draw
pause
goto :out

REM Play again or not
:out
echo GG Want to play again?
echo [1] = Yes
echo [2] = No
set /p Restart=
if %Restart% equ 1 goto :setting
if %Restart% equ 2 pause
```